# Spring Security OAuth 2 - Authorization Server update from 0.1.0 to 0.1.1 / 0.1.2 makes example projects not work

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, spring-security-oauth2

I want to use the new `Spring Security Authorization Server` to implement `OAuth2` for my webservice.

At https://www.baeldung.com/spring-security-oauth-auth-server an example is given, separation

- Authorizatin Server
- Resource Server
- Client

The code can be found at https://github.com/Baeldung/spring-security-oauth/tree/master/oauth-authorization-server

Those three Maven projects function in the given version, when the Client in the web browser accesses http://localhost:8080/articles the output is correctly

```
["Article 1","Article 2","Article 3"]
```

I tried to update the `Authorization Server` project to `0.1.1`, but although it compiles and starts, when the Client accesses http://localhost:8080/articles I get

```
Whitelabel Error Page

This application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you are seeing this as a fallback.
Sat Aug 07 15:57:26 CEST 2021
There was an unexpected error (type=None, status=999).
```

I thought this is because I have to update also the other versions in all three projects, to `Spring Boot 2.5.3` and also `OpenJDK 16`, but the same error.

I updated to `0.1.2` and changed the log level to `DEBUG`, this appears on startup of the Authorization Server project:

```
    ...
2021-08-09 17:54:45.876 DEBUG 16256 --- [           main] o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory     : Creating shared instance of singleton bean 'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.servlet.ServletWebServerFactoryConfiguration$EmbeddedTomcat'
    2021-08-09 17:54:46.015 DEBUG 16256 --- [           main] o.a.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener   : The Apache Tomcat Native library could not be found using names [tcnative-1, libtcnative-1] on the java.library.path [/usr/java/packages/lib:/usr/lib64:/lib64:/lib:/usr/lib]. The errors reported were [Can't load library: /home/myself/PROJECTs/SPRING/spring-authorization-server/bin/libtcnative-1.so, Can't load library: /home/myself/PROJECTs/SPRING/spring-authorization-server/bin/liblibtcnative-1.so, no tcnative-1 in java.library.path: /usr/java/packages/lib:/usr/lib64:/lib64:/lib:/usr/lib, no libtcnative-1 in java.library.path: /usr/java/packages/lib:/usr/lib64:/lib64:/lib:/usr/lib]
    
    org.apache.tomcat.jni.LibraryNotFoundError: Can't load library: /home/myself/PROJECTs/SPRING/spring-authorization-server/bin/libtcnative-1.so, Can't load library: /home/myself/PROJECTs/SPRING/spring-authorization-server/bin/liblibtcnative-1.so, no tcnative-1 in java.library.path: /usr/java/packages/lib:/usr/lib64:/lib64:/lib:/usr/lib, no libtcnative-1 in java.library.path: /usr/java/packages/lib:/usr/lib64:/lib64:/lib:/usr/lib
        at org.apache.tomcat.jni.Library.<init>(Library.java:101) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.50.jar:9.0.50]
        at org.apache.tomcat.jni.Library.initialize(Library.java:211) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.50.jar:9.0.50]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener.init(AprLifecycleListener.java:192) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.50.jar:9.0.50]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener.isAprAvailable(AprLifecycleListener.java:101) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.50.jar:9.0.50]
        at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatServletWebServerFactory.getDefaultLifecycleListeners(TomcatServletWebServerFactory.java:173) ~[spring-boot-2.5.3.jar:2.5.3]
        at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatServletWebServerFactory.<init>(TomcatServletWebServerFactory.java:120) ~[spring-boot-2.5.3.jar:2.5.3]
        at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.servlet.ServletWebServerFactoryConfiguration$EmbeddedTomcat.tomcatServletWebServerFactory(ServletWebServerFactoryConfiguration.java:76) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.5.3.jar:2.5.3]
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:78) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:567) ~[na:na]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:154) ~[spring-beans-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:653) ~[spring-beans-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:638) ~[spring-beans-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1334) ~[spring-beans-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1177) ~[spring-beans-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:564) ~[spring-beans-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:524) ~[spring-beans-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335) ~[spring-beans-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333) ~[spring-beans-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:213) ~[spring-beans-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.getWebServerFactory(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:217) ~[spring-boot-2.5.3.jar:2.5.3]
        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.createWebServer(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:180) ~[spring-boot-2.5.3.jar:2.5.3]
        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.onRefresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:160) ~[spring-boot-2.5.3.jar:2.5.3]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:577) ~[spring-context-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:145) ~[spring-boot-2.5.3.jar:2.5.3]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:754) ~[spring-boot-2.5.3.jar:2.5.3]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:434) ~[spring-boot-2.5.3.jar:2.5.3]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:338) ~[spring-boot-2.5.3.jar:2.5.3]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1343) ~[spring-boot-2.5.3.jar:2.5.3]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1332) ~[spring-boot-2.5.3.jar:2.5.3]
        at com.baeldung.OAuth2AuthorizationServerApplication.main(OAuth2AuthorizationServerApplication.java:10) ~[classes/:na]
...
```

It looks like the same happens with `0.1.1`

My pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.baeldung</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-authorization-server</artifactId>
    <version>0.1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.5.3</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security.experimental</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-oauth2-authorization-server</artifactId>
            <version>0.1.2</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <java.version>16</java.version>
    </properties>
</project>
```

Changing only the Authorization Server version in the pom.xml, 0.1.0 or 0.1.1 or 0.1.2 deliver all the same exception.

The example project from Baeldung only runs (delivers the articles from localhost:8080/articles) with 0.1.0, but with 0.1.1 and 0.1.2 I get the described Whitelable Error Page.

Comment: 0.1.2 is available, but same error.

Answer (score 3):

First, I would recommend you check out the [samples in the spring-authorization-server project](https://github.com/spring-projects-experimental/spring-authorization-server/tree/main/samples/boot/oauth2-integration) itself (see [this line](https://github.com/spring-projects-experimental/spring-authorization-server/blob/main/samples/boot/oauth2-integration/authorizationserver/src/main/java/sample/config/AuthorizationServerConfig.java#L76), for example), which will ensure you're keeping up with the rapid changes occurring in the project, as those tutorials on the web will tend to get out of date quickly.

Second, I believe the 2nd error in debug is not related to this issue, so that seems like a local setup issue, but I'm not 100% sure.

Third, the first error is happening on newer versions of SAS, due to [#243](https://github.com/spring-projects-experimental/spring-authorization-server/issues/243). The change included incorporating recommendations from [OAuth 2.1, Section 9.7.1](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-oauth-v2-1-01#section-9.7.1), which states:

> While redirect URIs using localhost (i.e.,
> "http://localhost:{port}/{path}") function similarly to loopback IP
> redirects described in Section 10.3.3, the use of "localhost" is NOT
> RECOMMENDED.  Specifying a redirect URI with the loopback IP literal
> rather than "localhost" avoids inadvertently listening on network
> interfaces other than the loopback interface.  It is also less
> susceptible to client-side firewalls and misconfigured host name
> resolution on the user's device.

This error only shows up on the redirect back to the client application, when the redirect URI has a host of `localhost`. If you enable trace logging in the authorization server (e.g. `logging.level.org.springframework.security=trace`) you will see a successful authentication, followed by a redirect to an error page, something like:

```
...
2021-08-10 11:10:41.596 DEBUG 90071 --- [io-9000-exec-10] w.a.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter : Set SecurityContextHolder to UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken [Principal=org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User [Username=user, Password=[PROTECTED], Enabled=true, AccountNonExpired=true, credentialsNonExpired=true, AccountNonLocked=true, Granted Authorities=[ROLE_PILOT]], Credentials=[PROTECTED], Authenticated=true, Details=WebAuthenticationDetails [RemoteIpAddress=127.0.0.1, SessionId=3786957448CCBB82DAE6AB29DBCA5D2C], Granted Authorities=[ROLE_USER]]
2021-08-10 11:10:41.596 DEBUG 90071 --- [io-9000-exec-10] o.s.s.web.DefaultRedirectStrategy        : Redirecting to http://auth-server:9000/error?response_type=code&client_id=messaging-client&scope=openid&state=Vg-fUjLSdOjAG_4Y9LcjcxxYTGhd33Trbaclp92XoDQ%3D&redirect_uri=http://localhost:8080/login/oauth2/code/messaging-client&nonce=s8hJD_zDopreLImNeRwQ3fslL4yFNySjbt6MiYK1mPw
...
```

This tells me there's something happened earlier in the flow, and we're only experiencing the symptom at this point. If you look higher up in the logs, prior to logging in, you'll see something like this:

```
...
2021-08-10 11:10:37.444 TRACE 90071 --- [nio-9000-exec-8] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Invoking OAuth2AuthorizationEndpointFilter (6/24)
2021-08-10 11:10:37.444 TRACE 90071 --- [nio-9000-exec-8] o.s.s.authentication.ProviderManager     : Authenticating request with OAuth2AuthorizationCodeRequestAuthenticationProvider (1/10)
2021-08-10 11:10:37.445 TRACE 90071 --- [nio-9000-exec-8] o.s.s.w.header.writers.HstsHeaderWriter  : Not injecting HSTS header since it did not match request to [Is Secure]
2021-08-10 11:10:37.445 DEBUG 90071 --- [nio-9000-exec-8] w.c.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository : Did not store empty SecurityContext
2021-08-10 11:10:37.445 DEBUG 90071 --- [nio-9000-exec-8] w.c.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository : Did not store empty SecurityContext
2021-08-10 11:10:37.445 DEBUG 90071 --- [nio-9000-exec-8] s.s.w.c.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter : Cleared SecurityContextHolder to complete request
2021-08-10 11:10:37.447 TRACE 90071 --- [nio-9000-exec-8] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Trying to match request against DefaultSecurityFilterChain [RequestMatcher=org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configurers.oauth2.server.authorization.OAuth2AuthorizationServerConfigurer$$Lambda$603/0x000000080041a040@4dd90166, Filters=[org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter@52227eb2, org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter@21263314, org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter@4d84049a, org.springframework.security.web.csrf.CsrfFilter@1d8b0500, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter@6413d7e7, org.springframework.security.oauth2.server.authorization.web.OAuth2AuthorizationEndpointFilter@32d5279, org.springframework.security.oauth2.server.authorization.oidc.web.OidcProviderConfigurationEndpointFilter@fe87ddd, org.springframework.security.oauth2.server.authorization.web.OAuth2AuthorizationServerMetadataEndpointFilter@448b808a, org.springframework.security.oauth2.server.authorization.web.NimbusJwkSetEndpointFilter@ebda593, org.springframework.security.oauth2.server.authorization.web.OAuth2ClientAuthenticationFilter@22d322f5, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter@4337afd, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.ui.DefaultLoginPageGeneratingFilter@d16be4f, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.ui.DefaultLogoutPageGeneratingFilter@5ad1904f, org.springframework.security.oauth2.server.resource.web.BearerTokenAuthenticationFilter@60e06f7d, org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter@4a92c6a9, org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter@64c781a9, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter@a146b11, org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter@642857e0, org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter@30c3ae63, org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor@550e9be6, org.springframework.security.oauth2.server.authorization.web.OAuth2TokenEndpointFilter@32ec9c90, org.springframework.security.oauth2.server.authorization.web.OAuth2TokenIntrospectionEndpointFilter@456bcb74, org.springframework.security.oauth2.server.authorization.web.OAuth2TokenRevocationEndpointFilter@3b332962, org.springframework.security.oauth2.server.authorization.oidc.web.OidcClientRegistrationEndpointFilter@58a2d9f9]] (1/2)
2021-08-10 11:10:37.447 TRACE 90071 --- [nio-9000-exec-8] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Trying to match request against DefaultSecurityFilterChain [RequestMatcher=any request, Filters=[org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter@1b01a0d, org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter@91f565d, org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter@67b355c8, org.springframework.security.web.csrf.CsrfFilter@79f90a3a, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter@414f87a9, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter@6e31d989, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.ui.DefaultLoginPageGeneratingFilter@1ddc6db2, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.ui.DefaultLogoutPageGeneratingFilter@2ed71727, org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter@46e3559f, org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter@3b83459e, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter@5261ec9, org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter@388623ad, org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter@22bdb1d0, org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor@416d56f2]] (2/2)
2021-08-10 11:10:37.447 DEBUG 90071 --- [nio-9000-exec-8] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Securing GET /error?response_type=code&client_id=messaging-client&scope=openid&state=Vg-fUjLSdOjAG_4Y9LcjcxxYTGhd33Trbaclp92XoDQ%3D&redirect_uri=http://localhost:8080/login/oauth2/code/messaging-client&nonce=s8hJD_zDopreLImNeRwQ3fslL4yFNySjbt6MiYK1mPw
...
```

So the error actually happens in `OAuth2AuthorizationEndpointFilter` and the error redirect gets saved as the target URL after authentication, then we're redirected to `/login`, and after authentication redirected back to `/error`, which generates a whitelabel error page.

The short term fix would be to ensure you are using `127.0.0.1` for your client application, instead of `localhost`, including changing the redirect URIs in your authorization server (see sample). But if you forget and launch your browser at `http://localhost:8080`, you'll still get this error. You can work around that for now with a filter in your client application like this:

```java
/**
 * This filter ensures that the loopback IP <code>127.0.0.1</code> is used to access the
 * application so that the sample works correctly, due to the fact that redirect URIs with
 * "localhost" are rejected by the Spring Authorization Server, because the OAuth 2.1
 * draft specification states:
 *
 * <pre>
 *     While redirect URIs using localhost (i.e.,
 *     "http://localhost:{port}/{path}") function similarly to loopback IP
 *     redirects described in Section 10.3.3, the use of "localhost" is NOT
 *     RECOMMENDED.
 * </pre>
 *
 * @see <a href=
 * "https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-oauth-v2-1-01#section-9.7.1">Loopback Redirect
 * Considerations in Native Apps</a>
 */
@Component
@Order(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE)
public class LoopbackIpRedirectFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter {

    @Override
    protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain filterChain)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        if (request.getServerName().equals("localhost")) {
            UriComponents uri = UriComponentsBuilder.fromHttpRequest(new ServletServerHttpRequest(request))
                    .host("127.0.0.1").build();
            response.sendRedirect(uri.toUriString());
            return;
        }
        filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
    }

}
```

I would encourage you to [open an issue](https://github.com/spring-projects-experimental/spring-authorization-server/issues/new/choose) to request an improvement to the way this error is handled. And if you're interested, we'd love to discuss it with you and get you involved in the project to help with this issue.

Comment: Steve, thanks for the effort. I didn't understand everything you stated, but I replaced "localhost" with "127.0.0.1" everywhere in the 3 Baeldung projects, and it behaved even worse. I didn't get the login page anymore.

Comment: I hope the Baeldung team will check and update their samples. Meanwhile I try the official samples.

Comment: Accept this answer if you felt it helped you

Comment: @Toerktumlare didn't you read my comment? It didn't help. And I won't continue trying with the Baeldung projects, until they check themself what is wrong.

Comment: I cannot give credit to an answer which in my case didn't solve the problem. How to accept an answer which I couldn't approve? I followed his recommendation to try the official samples.

Comment: I'm sorry it didn't solve your problem. One thing that might be helpful, if you're willing, would be to change this question to  "999 error on spring-authorization-server 0.1.2" or something like that. Since I specifically wanted to answer this question due to the fact that the 999 error *will* occur on 0.1.2, and has nothing to do with the tutorial you followed. If you were willing to do that, you could then accept the answer as an explanation of your error, instead of solving some other problem with the tutorial.

Comment: It is not working. The host in the request changes to 127.0.0.1. However, the redirect_uri remains with localhost like this - redirect_uri=http://localhost:8080/login/oauth2/code/api-client-oidc

Comment: I used a custom domain name with a mapping entry in hosts and it is working as expected

Comment: I think the `localhost` vs `127.0.0.1` makes a huge difference here.  I was by habit using http://localhost:port for my client bookmark but it was registered with 127.0.0.1. I think the error reporting should be improved by adding where the mismatch is while complaining about redirect_url parameter.

Answer (score 1):

I also faced the same problem. after four to five days of struggle I found out the solution.  In all examples issuer-uri is
http://auth-server:9000

i just added in the etc/hosts file the following entry

127.0.0.1 auth-server

that solved the problem

Comment: I want to use IP address, not something like 'auth-server', so to say I don't want to modifiy the host file. I cannot follow up on this right now, as I had to decide for a working intermediate solution with Keycloak, but may return to using Spring Security Auth Server later.

Answer (score -1):

The problem about this error:

```
 org.apache.tomcat.jni.LibraryNotFoundError: Can't load library: /home/myself/PROJECTs/SPRING/spring-authorization-server/bin/libtcnative-1.so
```

Despite being a stacktrace, it is a **DEBUG** log from SpringBoot libraries. It is not an ERROR or even a WARNING log.
It doesn't matter much. Most spingboot applications around the world probably have the same log.

You have activated DEBUG logs on your whole application, even in libraries. I do not recommend that by default, as it will log way too much.

Only enable DEBUG mode on the main package of you application. Then, activate DEBUG mode only on a specific library package when you need to debug them.

For instance, if you need to see the requests your mongodb-driver executes, your application.yml should look like that:

```
logging:
  level:
    root: INFO
    mymainpackage: DEBUG
    org:
      mongodb: DEBUG
```