# Spring Security Authorization Server (experimental) - Sample projects, from Gradle to Maven (Dependencies)

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, spring-security-oauth2

As recommended [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68693085/spring-security-oauth-2-authorization-server-update-from-0-1-0-to-0-1-1-0-1) I now want to try the sample projects given in the experimental Authorization Server project.

I use Maven, don't know much about Gradle. I assume, that the samples folder is independent of any other artifact in the Authorization Server project?

I created via `start.spring.io` the 3 projects, added the missing dependencies manually, and the `pom.xml` look like this:

authorizationserver

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.5.3</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>authorizationserver</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>authorizationserver</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>15</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jdbc</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security.experimental</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-oauth2-authorization-server</artifactId>
            <version>0.1.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

resourceserver

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.5.3</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>resourceserver</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>resourceserver</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>15</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-oauth2-resource-server</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

client

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.5.3</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>client</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>client</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>15</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-oauth2-client</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.thymeleaf.extras</groupId>
            <artifactId>thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity5</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webflux</artifactId>
            <version>5.3.9</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.projectreactor.netty</groupId>
            <artifactId>reactor-netty</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.10</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
            <artifactId>webjars-locator-core</artifactId>
            <version>0.47</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
            <artifactId>bootstrap</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
            <artifactId>jquery</artifactId>
            <version>3.6.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Are these pom.xml correct? Is anything missing, are the versions OK to use, etc.?

I want to change my webservice (Spring Boot, REST controllers) from `Basic Auth` to `OAuth2`. My webservice is build with Spring Boot 2.5.3 and OpenJDK 15 (might change to 16) and Maven. That's why I use the latest versions in the pom.xml. But sample projects don't specify versions or use older version, that's why I don't know what versions are OK to use.

Is `auth-server` necessary or can it be replaced with `127.0.0.1`?

AS

```
return new ProviderSettings().issuer("http://auth-server:9000")
-> 
return new ProviderSettings().issuer("http://127.0.0.1:9000")
```

RS

```
issuer-uri: http://auth-server:9000
->
issuer-uri: http://127.0.0.1:9000
```

Client

```
issuer-uri: http://auth-server:9000
->
issuer-uri: http://127.0.0.1:9000
```

Also, at https://github.com/spring-projects-experimental/spring-authorization-server/tree/main/samples/boot/oauth2-integration there are 4 projects.

The `README` says

```
Run Authorization Server 
Run Resource Server 
Run Client
```

what for is the project `authorizationserver-custom-consent-page` ?

I'm asking about the versions I use, latest in fact, because for example I need `OpenJDK 15` as I'm using `"""` all over the place in my webservice project (which will be the Resource Server in context of OAuth2). I cannot therefore switch to versions like `Java 8` or so, as stated here:

```
Prerequisites

Git and the JDK8 build.

Be sure that your JAVA_HOME environment variable points to the jdk1.8.0 folder extracted from the JDK download.
```

I'm not sure if my problems are related to newer versions of dependencies I use.

Meanwhile, with Maven all 3 projects compile and start, but I'm stuck at the login page. After giving the username and password, it remains on the login page. It seems to accept the user credentials, but loads the login page again. If I misspell the username or password, it complains bad credentials. This is with samples from the downloaded sources of 0.1.2.

It is not stated why `auth-server` has to be used, and therefore I did the replacements described earlier.

What value will be replaced for `registrationId` in `redirect-uri: "http://127.0.0.1:8080/login/oauth2/code/{registrationId}"` ?

Comment: Downloading the sources for 0.1.2 from https://github.com/spring-projects-experimental/spring-authorization-server/releases contains the corresponding samples.

Comment: not related to this, but you should give credit to steve in your last question for him taking the time to help you.

Comment: Thanks @Toerktumlare. Also, @neblaz I'm working on samples for Spring Authorization Server corresponding to those, but in the official [spring security samples](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security-samples/). For now, see the [spring authorization server sample](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security-samples/tree/main/servlet/spring-boot/java/oauth2/authorization-server), which should run without gradle dependencies on the SAS project, but instead depends on the artifact. `./gradlew bootRun` should get you up and running.

Comment: I consider the samples here https://github.com/spring-projects-experimental/spring-authorization-server/tree/main/samples/boot/oauth2-integration because this is the link you gave me in the other post. The samples are included in the releases here https://github.com/spring-projects-experimental/spring-authorization-server/releases which can be downloaded.

Comment: Did you managed to run the code? I also want to test it.